# Writing SQL with selected value as title and calculated sub-total

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, syntax

I need help writing my SQL query. I've got 3 tables.

### Here's a simplified example.

**Items**

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| First | desc 1 |
| Second | desc 2 |

**Item Detail**

| Name | Supplier | Reorder Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Amazon | 1 |
| Second | Sony | 100 |
| Third | Sony | 10 |

**Item Balance**

| Name | Warehouse | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | WH 1 | 10 |
| Second | WH 1 | 20 |
| Second | WH 2 | 10 |
| Third | WH 2 | 10 |

### This is what I'd like to get as a result:

**Item Balance**

| Supplier | Name | Reorder Level | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon |  |  |  |
|  | First | 1 | 10 |
|  |  |  | Subtotal 10 |
| Sony |  |  |  |
|  | Second | 100 | 30 |
|  | Third | 10 | 10 |
|  |  |  | Subtotal 40 |
|  |  |  | Total 50 |

What's the best way to get this kind of result in MySQL-style SQL?

Comment: ```GROUP BY .. WITH ROLLUP```

Comment: The vertical spacing is best done in the client, not SQL.

Comment: Yeah, I've used python to format and join the SQL results